# How do I properly create a Buffer object from a node native addon?

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I am using node 6.9.1 and I try to create a cpp addon that will create Node Buffer objects. After some research I came up with the following code:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <node_buffer.h>
#include <v8.h>

using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::HandleScope;
using v8::Isolate;

Local<Object> create_buffer(Isolate* isolate, char* rawData, int length) {
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  Local<Object> buf = node::Buffer::New(
    isolate,
    rawData,
    length).ToLocalChecked();
  return buf;
}
```

which I use as follows:

```
Local<Value> buff = create_buffer(isolate, rawData, length);
const unsigned argc = 1;
Local<Value> argv[argc] = { buff };
cb->Call(Null(isolate), argc, argv);
```

This code compiles just fine but causes an error when I access the .length property of the buffer I get through the callback:

```
Security context: 0x9d84c7cfb51 <JS Object>#0#
```

I found several tutorials but all of them use an earlier version of v8/node api and I cannot find any info what is a proper way to create buffer in the recent Node versions. Also it is possible that I have made a mistake somewhere. Thanks in advance if you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: It seems I should just use nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use NAN's [`NewBuffer`](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/buffers.md#api_nan_new_buffer) helper:

```
Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> mybuffer = Nan::NewBuffer(size);
Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> mybuffer = Nan::NewBuffer(mydata, size);
```

Node's [`node_buffer.h`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_buffer.h) also has a public constructor, but it's not necessarily consistent across versions.

I'm not positive, but your error might be because you've freed the raw data used to construct the buffer?

Comment: Thanks, with Nan it works great. I wonder when do I how to free my data? Can I free the data after I created a buffer? Or should I free it when the buffer is not needed at all?

Comment: @OleksiiRudenko If you use these helpers, then v8 owns the memory and will free it for you when the Buffer is GC'ed. There's a third form I didn't list (click the link) that lets you pass a `FreeCallback` if you need more control. Finally, you can use `Nan::CopyBuffer` (same doc page), which will `memcpy` the data so that you retain control of the original data.